# How to share my python game with friends who don't have python or pygame

Tags: python, pygame, share, py2app

Just finished making my first python game based on the space invaders game. Now I don't know exactly how to share it with my friends. I know that I should use py2app, but I haven't found good online instructions on how to do so.

This is how the project file looks like:

[image]

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: If they are your friends, encouraging them to get python and pygame is a friendly thing to do. As you have discovered, programming is fun. Why not share the joy? You can use the game as an incentive.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install pyinstaller` - this module can generate executables of python scripts.
Then simply run: `pyinstaller main.py` or whatever the main file is named and it will generate an executable including all needed modules (you can find the
generated package in new created `dist` folder).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org), which, as the name suggests, compiles Python programs to an executable format.

Edit: Just noticed you were using MacOS, here is [a Py2app tutorial](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead.